# Why Laravel doesn't care about array input validation?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Here is my validator:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'considerations' => 'required',
   'product_id.*'  => "required"
]);
```

It validates `considerations` as well. If `$request` be lack of `considerations` item, it throws:

> The considerations field is required.

Which is right. But it doesn't care about `product_id`. If I don't send that parameter it passes the validation as well. It will throw an error only if I send `product_id[0]` and no value for it. Then it will throw:

> The product_id.0 field is required.

But if I don't send `product_id` parameter, it doesn't care and doesn't throw any error. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I woud recommend looking at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put a validation on the `product_id` itself. E.g.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'considerations' => 'required',
   'product_id'  => "required|array",
   'product_id.*'  => "required"
]);
```

Comment: Your answer contains a great point .. I also need to check being `array` for `product_id` input. upvote

Answer (score 2):

Looks as though your validation rules are equivalent to saying

"Ensure any contents of the product_id array hold a value if the product_id field is provided"

I would add another rule which is `'product_id' => 'required'` to your validation array which should ensure that the product_id key is in the post fields too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
        $rules =   ['considerations' => 'required',
                   'product_id-token' => 'required|array'];
        $message = ['considerations.required' => 'Your validation message',
                   'product_id-token.required' => 'Your validation message',];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), $rules, $message);
```